# Symbols '$£¥ €' missing from font after ios system upgrade from 9 - 10

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, ios10

This is a strange one.

Font in question: GrotesqueMT-Regular.ttf

I have an array called currencyPickerData and I use this information to populate my HMSegmentedControl.

```
    let currencyPickerData = ["$", "€", "¥", "£","FREE"]
```

with iOS 9 this is what it looked like.

[iOS9 font is there!](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5feUHWffxoWQWZscDc0UlZXOEE/view?usp=sharing)

with iOS 10 the "$", "€", "¥", "£" symbols are missing, I can still use the HMSegmentedControl but 4 out of the 5 segments are just empty.

[iOS10 font is missing!](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5feUHWffxoWbWUzWFFwOW1tcWM/view?usp=sharing)

I have not upgraded to swift 3 worried about all the bugs it will cause. Do you think I should? Any help appreciated.

Comment: I can see a $ to the left? Is that using the same font?

Comment: @Eeshwar good eye! Nope it's a different font called Interstate-Bold.ttf

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to update the HMSegmentedControl framework! its working again Thanks!